# How to on click create a new window in an android project on eclipse?

Tags: android

I was trying to learn how to program with eclipse and I can't figure out how to on click of a button make a new window or just get rid of my current buttons and show others.

main activity.java
`import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
`main activity.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: you could either work with `Fragments` or could start a new `Activity` by `intent`

Comment: I just answered a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390942/onclick-listener-not-working-getting-no-errors/22392502#22392502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new activity on a button click you could use the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mybutton = (Button)findviewbyId(R.id.button1);

    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                      Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add it to my mainactivity.java and it gave me errors in mybutton, OnClickListener, View, FirstActivity & SecondActivity. Should I put it somewhere else, sorry if I'm asking too much. I usually program small apps in visual basic.

Comment: Can you post your code? Also make sure you add the xml code?

Comment: I just added a button for now, but later I'm going to add more. I haven't changed much because the action that my app begins with is this.

Comment: Thanks it just needed a few changes, nothing major.