# onClick Listener not working getting no errors

Tags: android

i am having issues getting the coding for onClick to work correctly i have a main activity that contains 8 buttons button 1 should open face book to a page 2,4,5,6 and 7 should open a web browser to defined page and button 8 to open phone dialer with preset number to call.  I can not get this to work with out crashing the app i can set one onclick listener to button 1 and get it to work but when i add the next one it crashes the app i get no errors in eclipse i was told to do it with a fragment to handle the onclicks but im lost on how to do this can any one help me with this coding???

This is what i have so far just for 2 buttons still haven't got the one to open face book or the one to open phone dialer but this is as far as i get then it crashes –  Jerry 33 mins ago

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        addButtonClickListner(); 
    } 

    public void addButtonClickListner() { 
        Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);                
        btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
             public void onClick(View arg) { 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.*****.com")); 
                  startActivity(intent); 
             } 
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Mind posting your code, I am certain someone on here can easily help you with this one.

Comment: This is what i have so far just for 2 buttons still haven't got the one to open face book or the one to open phone dialer but this is as far as i get then it crashes

Comment: import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonClickListner();
    }
    public void addButtonClickListner()
    {
        Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg)

Comment: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.*****.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } 
 {
        Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.*****.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: I have moved your code from the comments section to your question, however you missed a line of code (I believe) when you are adding your 3rd button. Would you mind looking over what I put in there and seeing what the name of the method is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead

....

```
package com.example.testcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
// Test code: import android.widget.TextView;

// Let your class implement the OnClickListener interface directly. This
// will let you use the onClickListener
class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // "find" our views by their id's in our activity's layout
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        //...... continue for button3 - button8

        // set our "click" listeners for each of our buttons
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //...... continue for button3 - button 8
    } 

    // Because our class implements the OnClickListener interface
    // it will be listening for "clicks". Because of this, we can
    // override the click listener's default onClick(View v) method.
    // View v is our view, or our button, that is "clicked".
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Test code: TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // This is the statement that will allow each of your buttons
        // to perform different processes. For my test code, I have each
        // button reset the TextView I have displayed in the top of my
        // layout.
        switch(v.getId()){  
        case R.id.button1:
            // Test code: text.setText("Button 1");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // Test code: text.setText("Button 2");
            break;
        //...... continue for button3 - button 8
        default:
            Log.d(getApplication().getPackageName(), "Button click error!");
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Please take a look at my comments. The portion that is commented as

```
// Test Code:
```

is code that is pretty much useless for what you are doing. The Test Code from the switch statement is what you need to replace with what you want to do with each individual button. It is also important to note that where I say "//...... continue for button3 - button8" I simply mean to repeat the pattern that I have started with the first two buttons with the remaining six.

If you would like to test it with my given test code, here is my layout (just make sure you erase "// Test Code: " so that the test code lines are no longer commented out:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press a button"
        android:id="@+id/text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTES:

It is important to understand that in "good" xml layouts, the "android:text=" portion will be set to 'android:text=@string/"string_id"' instead of some general string to help with localization.

Make sure you change the very top line that declares the package to whatever package you have the Activity placed in. The name of this package is found at "Application"/src/"package_name" and is usually something like com.example.applicationname

I also want to say that I have included the comments in the code so that it can be copied and pasted without having to revisit this link over and over again in case anyone wants to use the code as a guide, not because I wanted tons of code posted in the answer.

Comment: just follow this method...it's the best and easier to understand...and please take note of the class he is implementing...

Comment: THank You very much i will give this a shot today and comment back when done

Comment: Of course, if it works feel free to upvote and accept... I like points :P

Comment: it wont let me up vote i did except but I'm having an issue now with the app crashing when i load it in the emu it just come up that the app has stopped i was going to add my final code but i don't know how to add with out the character limit like you did above.

Comment: That is for another question I would think. Start another topic (aka "Ask a question") and post your code in your question. For how to put code directly into a question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

> Sometime onClick listener doesn't work because of some other
>   transparent view is on top of your view.